# i have error on visual studio 2010 in update data

Tags: visual-studio-2010

udah nyoba banyak cara tapi ini masih error,kira-kira kenapa ya?

```
            'melakukan edit data berdasarkan kode barang yang dipanggil
            cmd = New OleDbCommand("update tbl_barang set nama_barang = '" & TextBox2.Text & _
                                   "',jenis_barang='" & ComboBox1.Text & _
                                    "',satuan_barang='" & ComboBox2.Text & _
                                       "',harga_beli='" & TextBox3.Text & _
                                       "',harga_jual='" & TextBox4.Text & _
                                       "',stock='" & TextBox5.Text & _
                                       "' where kode_barang='" & TextBox1.Text & "'", conn)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("Data Berhasil Di Ubah !")
            Call clear()
            Call Form_Barang.tampil_barang()

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

database : db_penjualan.mdb (access)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAeyp.png)

error seperti itu
dibagian update data di : cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()